# Intellij refactor or change multiple line of code, put method call inside another method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, intellij-14

I have multiple java files and in each java file having more than 100 code line of following type (where the focus is on "method1" which takes hard coded values) :

```
x.method1("cat")
y.method1("dog")
z.method1("whale")
```

I want to wrap "method1" inside "method2", i.e above lines of code become :

```
x.method2(method1("cat"))
y.method2(method1("dog"))
z.method2(method1("whale"))
```

How do I changes all these line of code faster ?

Comment: hello, there is no ready tool to make such kind of refactoring automatically. Please create an issue at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA